Swift: conform to protocol with property already found on object but different type?
I have the following code:
class Car {
    
    var carRentCount:NSNumber?
    
}

protocol TestProtocol {
    
    var carRentCount:Int? { get }
    
}

extension Car: TestProtocol { /// ERROR: Type 'Car' does not conform to protocol 'TestProtocol'
    
    
    
}

TestProtocol defines var carRentCount:Int? { get }. If I put that in the Car extension it I get Invalid redeclaration of 'carRentCount'.
I cannot change the type of the carRentCount in Car, it needs to stay as NSNumber.
How can I have Car adopt TestProtocol without changing Car's property var carRentCount:NSNumber??

You cannot. You would have to create some other type that holds a Car (i.e. has a property var car: Car and conforms with carRentCount: Int? { car.carRentCount?.intValue }). Or you will need to change one of these pieces.
